# How to highlight my own syntax in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

I am developing my own Domain Specific Language (DSL) and the filename extension is `.xyz`.

Emacs doesn't know how to highlight syntax in `.xyz` files so I uausally turn on `typescript-mode` or `json-mode`. But the available syntax highlight mode is not good enough for me, so I am considering writing my own syntax highligher for Emacs editor. Any tips on this task? Any toolkit recommendation?

Alternatively, I would be happy with any available mode that highlights common keywords such as `class`, `string`, `list`, variables before `=`sign and after `@` sign, braces `{}`, brackets `[]`, question mark `?` and exclamation mark `!`. Any existing languages have similar syntax?

I am not color-blind and not picky on colors. Any syntax highligher that highlights above syntax can solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are satisfied with simple syntax highlighting for keywords and comments only, there is a helper for this called `define-generic-mode`, which is documented in the elisp manual.

Some examples of using it can be found in `generic-x.el` distributed with Emacs.

But highlighting of variable names is not covered by this.  For that, you need to be able to parse the DSL using `semantic`/`bovine`, as whether a particular string is interpreted as a variable name depends on context, and not just simple regexp matching.